# Disqus comments system

Tags: disqus

everyone. I'm currently hosting my blog on my friend's server, he gave me FTP access. Each blog post has it's own HTML page, and each HTML page calls the footer JavaScript file, which document.writes the Disqus comments system. There footer JavaScript file is one file, and multiple HTML pages call it. There is a different comment channel on each page, which is what I want.

However, I do not wish for my blog to remain on my friend's server forever, I plan on buying my own domain and my own server. I was wondering if I would lose all my comments if I move the site to a new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your own Disqus account or are you sharing your friend's? If you have your own account you can move to a new host or domain without any trouble, see http://docs.disqus.com/help/39/.

Update: I've never actually migrated my Disqus comments to a new domain, but the rest of the system is so easy to use, that I'm sure migrating can't be too difficult either :)

Comment: I'm using my own Disqus account. Thanks for that link, that helped.